# EF - How to edit the below model using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm sending some view model data from the client and would like to update the model. I know how to do this by calling a stored procedure, but would very much like to know how to do this using linq queries. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
[HttpPost]
         public JsonResult EditEmployee(Models.Employee employee) 
         {
             try
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {
                     using (emsCtx)
                     {
                         var employeeResults = (from q in emsCtx.Employees
                                                where q.Id == employee.Id
                                                //code to update the model.
                                                );                    
                               employeeData.Employees = employeeResults;         
                     }

                     return Json();
                 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update data in your db correspoding to an employee then check below your edited code:

```
     [HttpPost]
     public JsonResult EditEmployee(Models.Employee employee) 
     {
         try
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 using (emsCtx)
                 {
                     var employeeResults = (from q in emsCtx.Employees
                                            where q.Id == employee.Id
                                             select q
                                            ).FirstOrDefault();        
                     if(employeeResults!=null)
                     {             
                           employeeResults.Column1 = employee.Column1; 
                           employeeResults.Column2 = employee.Column2; 
                           employeeResults.Column3 = employee.Column3; 
                           employeeResults.Column4 = employee.Column4; 
                     }
                     emsCtx.SaveChanges();
                 }

                 return Json();
             }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error. "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"..Any suggestions please ?

Comment: got the above sorted by including (select q) after where clause. how can I store the results in an object and send it back to the client ? I'm getting some conversion error

Comment: I've got one more error as well. AT submit changes, i get Error 1 'DataAccess.TestEntities' does not contain a definition for 'SubmitChanges' and no extension method 'SubmitChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'DataAccess.TestEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think I've got them sorted by using SaveChanges(); Hope I'm going in the right direction ? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes you are right it will be SaveChanges. SubmitChanges is used in LINQ to SQL.